# Remove record from route table

Tags: networking, vpn

I use Ubuntu 22.04. I connect to VPN using L2TP IPSEC. I connect successfully but without the internet. I run the command `route -n` to see route table:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     50     0        0 ppp0
0.0.0.0         192.168.43.1    0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp0s20f3
10.0.3.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 lxcbr0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp0s20f3
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
185.117.115.50  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
185.117.115.50  192.168.43.1    255.255.255.255 UGH   600    0        0 wlp0s20f3
192.168.43.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp0s20f3
192.168.43.1    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    600    0        0 wlp0s20f3
```

In this case, I need to remove the record `185.117.115.50 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255 UH 0 0 0 ppp0`. I think that it is the reason for no internet after a successful connection.

How to remove this record?

Answer (score 0):

I removed this entry by command and the internet appears! Unfortunately, it is each time action.

```
sudo ip route del 185.117.115.50 via 0.0.0.0 dev ppp0
```

How to remove this entry permanently?
How to find source which add this entry each time?

Answer (score 0):

```
mkdir temp_l2tp
cd temp_l2tp
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/n/network-manager-l2tp/network-manager-l2tp_1.20.8-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i network-manager-l2tp_1.20.8-1_amd64.deb
```

I had the same issue. This bug is fixed in v1.20.8 of network-manager-l2tp, you just need to upgrade to at least 1.20.8. See https://github.com/nm-l2tp/NetworkManager-l2tp/releases/tag/1.20.8 for more info.

*- Undo PTP peer & ext GW routing prevention workaround first introduced with NetworkManager-l2tp 1.8.4, as workaround no longer works with NetworkManager 1.36.*

This bug is not present in Ubuntu >=23.04 as there is already present v1.20.8